# Retrieve each value from a specific key with json

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to know if there is a way to get every values of "-temp" from the `.json`

```
{
  "weather":{
    "notes":{
      "cities":[
        {
          "-id":"scranton",
          "-temp":"17"
        },
        {
          "-id":"paris",
          "-temp":"16"
        },
        {
          "-id":"new york",
          "-temp":"18"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

How I tried to get it with JavaScript but that didn't work and I get `undefined`

`data.weather.notes.cities['-temp']`

How can I get every value of "-temp"?

Comment: you'll need a loop, then `data.weather.notes.cities[i]['-temp']`. Also, if you can modidy this `data`, try to avoid those `-` in the properties' name

Comment: @CalvinNunes Can you give me an example?

Comment: examples added by others in the answers, I would go with @ZERO answer, that uses a `map` to loop and return the expected temp values

Answer (score 4):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
const temps = data.weather.notes.cities.map(city => city["-temp"]);

console.log(temps); // ["17", "16", "18"]
```

Of course you can always access to them individually:

```
const { cities } = data.weather.notes;

console.log(cities[0]["-temp"]); // "17"
```

Or loop all of them:

```
for (let city of cities) {
  console.log("temperature in %s is %s°", 
    city["-id"], city["-temp"]
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly iterate through all the cities and gather the "-temp" keys.

```
data.weather.notes.cities.forEach(function(element) {
 for (var em in element) {
    if (em == "-temp")
    {
      console.log(element[em])
    }
 }
});
```

@ZER0 answer is probably the best though.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = {
  "weather":{
    "notes":{
      "cities":[
        {
          "-id":"scranton",
          "-temp":"17"
        },
        {
          "-id":"paris",
          "-temp":"16"
        },
        {
          "-id":"new york",
          "-temp":"18"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};
  
for(var i in data.weather.notes.cities) {
    let city = data.weather.notes.cities[i];
    console.log(city["-temp"]); //You_ can get it here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use JSON the same way you use jquery selectors. In your case, you need to map your array of cities.

```js
const object = {
  "weather":{
    "notes":{
      "cities":[
        {
          "-id":"scranton",
          "-temp":"17"
        },
        {
          "-id":"paris",
          "-temp":"16"
        },
        {
          "-id":"new york",
          "-temp":"18"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};

const tempList = object.weather.notes.cities.map(city => city['-temp']);

//result: ["17", "16", "18"]
```

See [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Map) documentation for further information.

Comment: Please note that it is not recommended to start your property label with special characters, like "-", as you made in "-temp"